# Does multiplication of tensors satisfy associative law?

Tags: tensor-products

I am a Ph.D. student in solid mechanics. I am very confused regarding a formula in a book named Tensor Analysis with Applications in mechanics.  On p. 59 we are given the following:

$${}$$

[image]

---

$${}$$

Note that the book uses the convention that  $\tilde{e}_i \tilde{e}_j = \tilde{e}_i \bigotimes \tilde{e}_j$ (it is a dyad).

Why are we able to combine $a^{ij}e_ie_j$ in the parentheses?

A similar situation is the following identity:
$$\mathbf{Q} \cdot \mathbf{T} \cdot (\mathbf{Q}^T \cdot \mathbf{Q} )\cdot \boldsymbol{u} = (\mathbf{Q} \cdot \mathbf{T} \cdot \mathbf{Q}^T) \cdot \mathbf{Q} \cdot \boldsymbol{u}.$$

Why do we appear to be able to move the parentheses anywhere? Does the multiplication of tensors satisfy some form of associative law, that allows us to do this? If so, how is such a law derived?

Comment: Looks like they (or you) sometimes write $\mathbf{xy}$ for $\mathbf{x}\otimes\mathbf{y}$ and sometimes they write this as $\mathbf{xy^\top}$. Pretty sloppy notation. Please post more details from the book.

Comment: @KurtG. In mechanics, if **x** is a base (also is  a vector) of a coordinate,  the vector **x** can correspond to a 3 \times 1 matrix, then **x** \otimes **y** (**x** and **y** is basis)  \mapsto **xy** ^{T}

Comment: This comment is unreadable. I know what you mean by $\mathbf{x}$ being a vector. What is a "base of a coordinate" ? BTW I am familiar with tensor calculus. The quick and dirty answer is that your objects there are either ordinary matrices or ordinary vectors and you are just in linear algebra. There we know that matrix/vector multiplication is associative.

Comment: @KurtG. Sorry about the format of my comment. This is my first time in stackexchange, I don't familiar with displaying formular in mini-Markdown. I know tensor is different from matrix, but I have to understand the rules of  tensor by matrix sometimes. So, how do I understading the associative of tensor dot product without the help of matrix/vector.
I fell dyad is bases $\otimes$ bases, it is a particular vector, not any vector, so I written the base of a coordinate.

Comment: You ask a very important question, and I do not know why it remains closed.  Let me try to help you with some comments in the meantime.  There are two types of products involved in your calculations.  Firstly the tensor product: $$\otimes: V\times W \to V\otimes W.$$  Secondly application of linear forms to vectors: $$\cdot: V^* \times V \to \mathbb{R},\qquad \cdot: V\times V^* \to \mathbb{R}.$$ 
 If we have a basis $\{e_i|i\in I\}$ for $V$ and a dual basis for $V^*$: $\{e^i|i\in I\}$, then $$e_i \cdot e^j=e^j\cdot e_i=\delta^{j}_i.$$

Comment: You are right to question associativity.  However it is not too hard to show that the order in which you perform the above contractions does not matter.  For example: $$\left(e^i \cdot (e_j\otimes e_k)\right)\cdot e^l=\delta^i_j e_k\cdot e^l=\delta^i_j\delta_k^l=e^i\cdot e_j\delta_k^l=e^i \cdot\left( (e_j\otimes e_k)\cdot e^l\right).$$

Comment: Returning to your question, let $$Q=q_r^ke_ke^r.$$ I am suppressing $\otimes$ from now on, like the author.  We have \begin{eqnarray}a^{ij}(Q\cdot e_i)(Q\cdot e_j)&=&a^{ij}q_r^ke_k(e^r\cdot e_i)q_s^le_l(e^s\cdot e_j)\\ &=&a^{ij}q_r^ke_k \delta^r_i q_s^le_l\delta^s_j \\&=&a^{ij}q_i^k q_j^le_ke_l \end{eqnarray} On the other hand $$Q^T=q_s^le^s e_l,$$ so we have \begin{eqnarray*} Q\cdot a^{ij} e_ie_j \cdot Q^T&=& a^{ij} q_r^kq^l_s e_k(e^r.e_i)(e_j\cdot e^s)e_l\\&=&a^{ij} q_r^kq^l_s e_k\delta^r_i\delta^s_je_l\\&=&a^{ij} q_i^kq^l_j e_ke_l\end{eqnarray*}